# Add new / low rep users to chat rooms created "continue discussion in chat" by gold tag badge holders (or alike privilege based)

Tags: discussion, chat, new-users, privileges

According to [Moderator moves comments to chat - can low-rep user participate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335485/289691), low rep users are allowed to chat when a discussion is moved to a chat room by a moderator, but not when the chat room is created by someone else.

What about allowing high SME (gold tag-badge holders or >10k users in large sites >5k users on small sites) to automatically "invite" to chat new users / low rep users that have been participating in a post discussion? If so, should this be allowed only on OP's first question or is it something that makes sense to be allowed on any question?

---

There are several older related [feature-requests](/questions/tagged/feature-requests):

- [I'd like to propose that users with high reputation be able to chat with users with low reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134828/289691) from 2012, votes +50
- [Grant chat privs to users who don't have enough reputation yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186384/289691) from 2013, votes +50 (posted as answer -> [Propose a privilege to sit in the 500 reputation mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186373/289691))
- [Suggested Privilege: Inviting new users to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277652/289691) from 2016, votes +22
- [Let's make it easier to get a room](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288572/289691) from 2016, votes +58

At least one of the above posts and other related ones (i.e. allow guests / users without SE accounts, bring chat to 21st century) are included in [Magic wand time - what does your community need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367906/289691) from 2021.

Feature requests form Meta Stack Overflow

- [Room owners should be allowed to accept <20 rep users to talk in a room](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257949/1595451) from 2014, votes +234
- [Proposal: Possibillity to start chat with low rep users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284876/1595451)
- [Can we lower the minimum reputation points requirement for chat based on other factors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318097/1595451)

Comment: Does the ability for sub-20 users to be allowed to chat exist in the existing chat interface? I think something like that was possible for a mentoring test a while back,

Comment: Or we could redesign the comment system so comments don't need to get shuffled into chat room purgatory. We could have a page separate from the questions and answers for discussion and promote valuable comments from the discussion so they appear under the posts. The current system is backward -- having to move/delete everything that isn't valuable takes to much focus and causes a lot of angst. The current system also incentivizes writing answers in comments instead of as proper answers.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, already exists but it's limited to chat rooms created when a mod moves comments

Answer (score 1):

Considering that low rep users are allowed to comment only on their own questions, I think that it makes sense to add this feature to any post.

---

On and ideal world *good enough new users* will not stay with rep <20 after a couple of posts but I have seen several cases in Stack Overflow where users have 5 or more posts, not being banned, so it's fair to assume that their posts are not *very low quality* / are good enough to be keep, at least for a while.

Several of them have gained some rep by accepting answers so it looks that they are understanding a bit about how the Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange model work. When reviewing their previous posts sometimes they got code only answers with no explanation and some of the newer questions are follow-up questions about new issues derived from those answers, some time misguiding the OP. On few of these cases I posted an answer and closed as duplicate (duphammer) one of the follow-up questions. Being able to invite the OP to chat might help to save a lot of time and will keep the visible comments minimal.